# Insertar los elementos de dos listas en una tabla de Base de datos

Tags: python, sqlite

Por ejemplo tengo dos listas:

```
nombres = ['JUAN PEREZ', 'CARLOS HERNANDEZ', 'JOSE SOTO']
ruts = ['12345678-9', '98765432-1', '65432198-K']
```

Mi objetivo es guardar en una tabla los nombres con su respectivo rut, por ejemplo así:

```
|id|nombre          |rut       
|1 |JUAN PEREZ      |12345678-9
|2 |CARLOS HERNANDEZ|98765432-1
|3 |JOSE SOTO       |65432198-K
```

El tema está en que la lista puede tener más elementos (es dinámica), eso sí siempre va a ser relacional el indice de ambas listas (el `nombres[0]` va de la mano con el `ruts[0]`, el `nombres[1]` va de la mano con el `ruts[1]` y así sucesivamente).

Entonces mi duda es en como puedo ir guardando todos los datos independientemente del largo de las listas.

Comment: puedes obtener la longitud de tu array, y hacer un ciclo, en cada iteracción obtienes el elemento `nombres[indice]`,  `ruts[indice]`, y generas el insert

Comment: Listo ya lo solucioné, publicaré como lo hice, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que hice fue hacer un bucle for para que recorriera desde el indice 0 hasta el largo de la lista. Y con aquello pude ingresar los datos a la base de datos.

```
for x in range(0,len(nombres)):
    print(nombres[x], ruts[x])
    
    data = Persona(nombres[x], ruts[x])
    db.session.add(Persona)
    db.session.commit()
```